# How to correct the `ErrorHandlingUtils:155, repeated measurement` warning for the writing process in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I am running the writing data process in Apache IoTDB, a warning mentioned: `WARN o.a.i.d.u.ErrorHandlingUtils:155 - Exception occurred while processing non-query.rg.apache.iotdb.db.exception.query.QueryProcessException:Insertion contains duplicated measurement: connection closed`. What is the reason for this? What is a repeated measurement mentioned in this warning and how should I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you execute any insertion like `insert into root.sg.d1(time,s1,s1) values(1,1,1)` command to Apache IoTDB. This error means repeated time series are written in one writing progress, so check whether any monitoring indicators are repeated and you should be able to find where this error comes from.